# Inserting nodes into a singly linked list based on size of number

Tags: java, linked-list

> Given a set of numbers insert them so that they are ordered ie.
>
> ```
> add(5)
> add(3)
> add(6)
> add(2)
>
> Output: 6 5 3 2
>
> GetNumber() returns the number of that term
> insertAfter() inserts that node after the pointer
> insertAtHead() inserts as the head node
> Term is the Node which holds the number
> ```

How can I refactor this working code?

```
        boolean inserted = false;        
        Node pointer = head;
    if (pointer == null || term.getNumber() > pointer.data.getNumber()) {
        // If head is empty insert there or if term is larger than head.
        insertAtHead(term);
    } else if(pointer.next == null) {
        insertAfter(term, head);
    } else {
        while (pointer.next != null) {
            //Insert at end.
            if (term.getNumber() > pointer.next.data.getNumber()) {
                insertAfter(term, pointer);
                inserted = true;
                break;
            }
            pointer = pointer.next;
        }
        if (!inserted) {
            //If not inserted it must be the smallest so add to the end.
            insertAfter(term, pointer);
        }
    }
    printList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need the `else if(pointer.next == null)` case, it's covered by `if (!inserted)`.
- Declare variables in as small a scope as possible to increase readability. `inserted` and `pointer` aren't needed until the while loop.
- You can save a nesting level if you put your code into a `insertSorted` method, and then call `printList` afterwards in the calling method. That way, you can write the initial head insert as a guard clause and thus save the else.
- You could also save the break by adding `&& !inserted` to the while clause.
- many of your comments just repeat the code they comment on, and are thus not really needed.
- `// Insert at end.` is quite misleading, as the insert doesn't happen at the end of the list.

With all these changes, your code already looks a bit cleaner:

```
if (head == null || term.getNumber() > head.data.getNumber()) {
    insertAtHead(term);
    return;
}

Node pointer = head;
boolean inserted = false;
while (pointer.next != null && !inserted) {
    if (term.getNumber() > pointer.next.data.getNumber()) {
        insertAfter(term, pointer);
        inserted = true;
    }
    pointer = pointer.next;
}

if (!inserted) {
    //If not inserted it must be the smallest so add to the end.
    insertAfter(term, pointer);
}
```

You could also return early after inserting, and thus get rid of the `inserted` variable:

```
// guard clause for head insert

Node pointer = head;
while (pointer.next != null) {
    if (term.getNumber() > pointer.next.data.getNumber()) {
        insertAfter(term, pointer);
        return;
    }
    pointer = pointer.next;
}

//If not inserted it must be the smallest so add to the end.
insertAfter(term, pointer);
```

But you still have a separate case for the last insert which is a bit ugly. You should be able to get rid of it with something like this:

```
// guard clause for head insert

Node pointer = head;
while (pointer.next != null && term.getNumber() < pointer.next.data.getNumber()) {
    pointer = pointer.next;
}
insertAfter(term, pointer);
```

Comment: That is fantastic thank you so much @tim !